# Android Studio cannot install GPU Debugging Tools in Linux Mint

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, gpu, failed-installation

Whenever I try,Android Studio shows:

Packages to install: 
- GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)

Preparing "Install GPU Debugging tools (revision: 3.1.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gapid_2994895_linux.zip
This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gapid_2994895_linux.zip
Failed packages:
- GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)

Comment: Your post got flagged for moderation since it's you're a new poster.  Generally, looks good.  One tweak would be to add the more specific tag android-studio.

Comment: ok thanks buzz3791

Comment: Likely the root `/` was just full; those package operations unpack to `/tmp`, unless sym-linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh It Seems that Android Studio could not unzip or download the file,
so all I needed to do was download manually gapid, unzip, and put in a folder called gapid at "Android/Sdk/extras/google"